# function pointer with parameters in python?

Tags: python, api, function-pointers, cron-task

I'm reading the docs from pythons [Cron-job](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/cronschedule.html#example-1) (Example 1):

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

def job_function():
    print "Hello World"

# Schedules job_function to be run on the third Friday
# of June, July, August, November and December at 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 and 03:00
sched.add_cron_job(job_function, month='6-8,11-12', day='3rd fri', hour='0-3')
```

is it possible to add paremters to that `job_function` and how to pass them to `add_cron_job`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `args` keyword argument:

```
# call job_function with arguments 'hello' and 'world'
sched.add_cron_job(job_function, args=('hello', 'world'), month='1', day='1st fri', hour='0')
```

See [the definition of `add_cron_job`](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/4aa5683f5d82/apscheduler/scheduler.py#cl-329).